# How can I catch 410 error from `postToConnection` call via golang aws sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am using websocket apigateway in AWS to manage websocket connections. There are cases that the connection is disconnected but the `@disconnect` route is not triggered. In this case, `postToConnection` api call will return 410 error.

I am using golang sdk `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/apigatewaymanagementapi`. The `postToConnection` API returns `PostToConnectionOutput, error`. How can I detect whether the error is 410 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the returned error is a type of `GoneException`

See https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/handling-errors/

```
    import(
      api "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/apigatewaymanagementapi"
      apitypes "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/apigatewaymanagementapi/types"
    )
    


    func main() {
        
        svc := api.New(api.Options{
            Region: "your-region",
        })
    
        output, err := svc.PostToConnection(ctx, &api.PostToConnectionInput{
            ConnectionId: aws.String("your-connection-id"),
        })
    
        if err != nil {
            var gne *apitypes.GoneException
            if errors.As(err, &gne) {
                log.Println("error:", gne.Error())
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: just a question about the type. You decline `gne` as `*apitypes.GoneException` which is a pointer. But take the address again in `errors.As(err, &gne)`. Is it correct?